# Nietzsche said: Everyone knows at present that the ability to endure contradiction is a good indication of culture

Tags: nietzsche

Nietzsche said:

> Everyone knows at present that the ability to endure contradiction is a good indication of culture.

What does that mean, and what was he most likely trying to say, stating that?

Comment: I wonder if he was intuiting a version of this concept, developed later https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguity_tolerance%E2%80%93intolerance Not rushing to judgement, holding space to 'court opposition' can allow more development of and depth of, and more robustness of ideas than a more narrowed prejudge-ing approach, simply asserting and ending debate.

Comment: i do not know te difference from keats https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_capability @CriglCragl

Answer (score 1):

That while the uncultured can not endure contradiction from other people -- that is, opposition -- the cultured are able to cope with it.

He then adds

> Some people even know that the higher man courts opposition, and provokes it, so as to get a cue to his hitherto unknown partiality.

which shows that some of them actively use it.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. i think it was a little ambiguity there. as i get it now, saying "contradiction" he didn't mean "contradiction, as in paradoxes, like things that contradict very thing they are stating, hypocritically" but rather "contradiction, as just opposition and pressure from other parties". i think it was the reason i couldn't comprehend it whatsoever.